# Switching between a test database and production database?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection-string

What is the best way to easily switch from a test database to a production database in vb.net and MySql, when all MySql connection strings are currently hard coded?

Comment: That's exactly why you shouldn't hard code them.

Comment: I think you've already answered your own question :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, this was someone else project that I just picked up so I'm running into a lot of silly things like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the time to move them to a configuration file. It might be a little more work now, but over the life of the project you will make up that time.

Answer (score 4):

Migrate the hard coded connection strings into a config file.

It's certainly not a difficult procedure.

Comment: That depends on what you call "difficult."  I'm adding a few features to a site that was programmed years ago, with everything hard-coded.  I plugged the most obvious SQL and script injections with a servlet that stupidly filters anything dangerous because I wouldn't have enough time to add the features I've been tasked to do in the allotted time if I refactored it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I currently use two options.

1) Take advantage of [web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx). It allows you to easily define your test and production environments, and will recompile the web.config file based on Visual Studio's build configuration. I outline this a little in my blog [here](http://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/tame-your-configurationdeployments-with-web-config-transforms/).

2) If you can't go that "advanced", add your configurations into your connectionStrings section of your web.config in the following naming conventions:

- databasename.DEV
- databasename.PROD

Once this is complete, you can create a simple function that pulls the proper connection string based on the environment on the server. For instance, if the current server's name is X, then pull the connection string from the PROD profile, otherwise use the DEV profile. It makes for a little extra work, but allows to keep everything in a single config file but still changes things without having to comment/uncomment various sections in your web.config file.